# Negative number end the program using for loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Hi guys I don't quite understand how to use a for loops as we just started learning them today. I have to add a for loop to a program that we made earlier. It has to keep asking for the dogs age until the user inputs a negative number. Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DogYears
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your dog's age in human years: ");
        int age = scan.nextInt();

        int dogAge = age * 7;
        System.out.println("Your dog is " + age + " in human years and "
            + dogAge + " in dog years!");

        if (dogAge >= 150)
            System.out.println("Likely story");
        else if (dogAge >= 80 && dogAge < 150)
            System.out.println("Hello grand-dog");
        else if (dogAge >= 40 && dogAge < 80)
            System.out.println("Boring!");
        else if (dogAge >= 20 && dogAge < 40)
            System.out.println("Get a job!");
        else if (dogAge < 20)
            System.out.println("Just a pup!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use a for loop for this.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int age = 1;
    System.out.print("Enter your dog's age in human years: (or a negative number to exit)");
    for(;age>=0;){
       age = scan.nextInt();
       int dogAge = age * 7;
       System.out.println("Your dog is "+age+" in human years and "+dogAge+" in dog years!");
       if(dogAge>=150)System.out.println("Likely story");
       else if (dogAge>=80 && dogAge<150) System.out.println("Hello grand-dog");
       else if(dogAge>=40 && dogAge<80)System.out.println("Boring!");
       else if(dogAge>=20 && dogAge<40)System.out.println("Get a job!");
       else if(dogAge<20)System.out.println("Just a pup!");
    }
}
```

However, it isn't the best syntax to use. A while loop would be easier to understand in this situation.

The reason this works is because of the `for` loop syntax.

A for loop requires 3 pieces:

- A variable
- A boolean value
- an incrementer

The for loop initialization looks like this:

```
for(var;boolean;incrementer){
     //...
}
```

However, you don't actually need an incrementer or a boolean or even a variable.

`for(;;){/*...*/}` is perfectly valid code and will loop until something does a `break;` out of it.

So, we take advantage of that fact by really only using the boolean value in our For loop initialization.

You could even write it as:

```
for(;age>=0;){/*...*/}
```

as long as the variable `age` is initialized before the for loop.

Comment: Yes that is true but he wants us to get familiar with for loops.

Comment: So if the `0` is enterd, meaning that dog is not born yet. This cannot be happening. And this for loop statement is compile error

Comment: @codebot What is the compile error you are getting? If `0` is entered that means a negative value wasn't entered and the loop should continue. I think that follows the instructions.

Comment: @user4068770 I added an explanation for `for` loops and why this works. Let me know if you need more of an explanation.

Comment: Thank you that does help. I will try doing another for loop on one of my other programs we did.

Comment: @codebot You could look for what is causing the error using debug, you will find that I was initializing the same variable twice. Thank you for pointing out the compile error. The correct code is now reflected in my answer.

Comment: No Problem @Enigmadan. Thanks for the edit. Voted up!

Answer (score 0):

With For Loop:

```
   for(;age>=0;){
          int dogAge = age * 7;
          System.out.println("Your dog is "+age+" in human years and "+dogAge+" in dog years!");


      if(dogAge>=150)System.out.println("Likely story");
      else if (dogAge>=80 && dogAge<150) System.out.println("Hello grand-dog");
      else if(dogAge>=40 && dogAge<80)System.out.println("Boring!");
      else if(dogAge>=20 && dogAge<40)System.out.println("Get a job!");
      else if(dogAge<20)System.out.println("Just a pup!");
      System.out.print("Enter your dog's age in human years: ");
      age = scan.nextInt();

    }
```

as you only have the terminating condition for the loop then use only that part.

```
for(INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; INCREMENT/DECREMENT){
    // Code for the for loop's body
    // goes here.
}
```

You donot have to initialize and you donot have to increment or decrement just use the condition part

Comment: He told us that we HAVE to use a "for" loop and I've tried almost everything I know but still stuck

Comment: @user4068770 with for loop

Answer (score 0):

Simply do like this. I know you already know what's happening in this code and the for loop here is like a while loop. And also try to use braces with you if, else. It's a good code practice.

```
class DogYears {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your dog's age in human years: ");
    int age = scan.nextInt();

    for (; age > 0;) {
        int dogAge = age * 7;
        System.out.println("Your dog is " + age + " in human years and " + dogAge + " in dog years!");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        if (dogAge >= 150) {
            System.out.println("Likely story");
        } else if (dogAge >= 80 && dogAge < 150) {
            System.out.println("Hello grand-dog");
        } else if (dogAge >= 40 && dogAge < 80) {
            System.out.println("Boring!");
        } else if (dogAge >= 20 && dogAge < 40) {
            System.out.println("Get a job!");
        } else if (dogAge < 20) {
            System.out.println("Just a pup!");
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.print("Enter your dog's age in human years: ");
        age = scan.nextInt();

    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you this helped a lot! But I changed the for loop so every negative answer would end the program. Thanks again

Comment: My pleasure. change your for loop like `for (; age > 0;)`. Then you will be fine. Thanks